# Mongoose rendering findById

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

Hey I'm trying build flash game site. After I click one game it opens a page which I'm rendering with `findById` like:

```
router.get("/oyun/:gameNameId", (req, res) => {
    gameName.findById(req.params.gameNameId)
        .then((gamesInfo) => {
            console.log(gamesInfo);
            res.render("showGame", {
                gamesInfo: gamesInfo
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("errr errr errrr");
            console.log(err);
            res.send(err);
        });
});
```

My problem is on this page I want to show the popular games dynamically like:

```
<% gamesInfo.forEach((game)=>{ %>
    <% if(game.popular =="true") { %> 
        <li>
            <a href="/oyun/<%= game._id %>" class="sa">
                <img src="<%=game.gameImg%>" alt="">
            </a>
            <span><%=game.gameName%></span>
        </li>
     <% }  
})%>
```

But because I'm rendering the page just with one game I can't do that. Also I can't render page without `findById`. So I'm stuck I don't know how to do. If anybody has a solution I will be glad to hear it.

Comment: Have you tried passing the page an array of the popular games?

Comment: Maybe `find` some more?

Comment: yes its say "gamesInfo.forEach is not a function "

Comment: Are you building a game's detail page having a widget of popular games ? correct ?

Comment: Jonas W. unfortunately  its not working when im try like gameName.find({gameNameId: req.params.gameNameId}).

Comment: Farhan Tahir this is the page when you clicking the game and you start play but also i want to show popular games on right site of page .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i find the solution by rendering double mongoose query like :

```
router.get("/oyun/:gameNameId",(req,res)=>{
        gameName.findById( req.params.gameNameId , function(err, gamesInfo){
            if(err) {
              console.log(err);
              return
            } 
            gameName.find({}, function(err, gamesI){
                if(err) {
                  console.log(err);
                  return
                }
            res.render("showGame",{gamesInfo:gamesInfo , gamesI: gamesI});
    });
});
});
```

and

```
<% gamesI.forEach((game)=>{ %>
    <% if(game.popular =="true") { %> 
        <li>
            <a href="/oyun/<%= game._id %>" class="sa">
                <img src="<%=game.gameImg%>" alt="">
            </a>
            <span><%=game.gameName%></span>
        </li>
     <% }  
})%>
```

i didn't konw i must to call multiple queries .

Comment: That's what I tried bringing across with my comment, this is how you do it most elegantly ;)

Comment: my problem was .I didn't know at i can call two queries . :)

Comment: What did you think? I mean to me it seems pretty clear that you can return the response of more than one function to the client

Comment: Before I find the solution. I was thinking i can return just one query from database ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
<% for(var i=0;i<gamesInfo.length;i++){ %>
        <% if(gamesInfo[i].popular =="true") { %> 
            <li>
                <a href="/oyun/<%= gamesInfo[i]._id %>" class="sa">
                    <img src="<%=gamesInfo[i].gameImg%>" alt="">
                </a>
                <span><%=gamesInfo[i].gameName%></span>
            </li>
         <% }  
    }%>
```